# How to stop my emails to be sent as bulk email?

Tags: .net, bulk-mail

I have a reason to do that.

I have recorded a voice message, attached with email, and sent it to several companies. One company, takes that voice message/email, and send it to millions of people.

I want to stop resend of my email/voice recording.

I am C# develop, one of my client asked me this question. I asked him to introduce verification codes, so that nobody will be able to listen the voice but still emails would be sent to millions of poeple.

Any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Host your audio file on a website, then provide a link to that audio file in your emails. That way all your emails are light-weight and are not clogging people's inboxes.

Comment: If you're hosting the file, you can control who has access to it and for how long.  You can also set up an authentication system on your own site that forces users to verify their email address (and maybe an auth token) to listen to the recording.  This makes your audio much more secure and prevents anyone from redistributing.

Comment: But all someone has to do is download the file, then spam it out to millions of people. If someone can listen to the audio, it's on their computer.

Comment: @EAMann - Exactly, you could have each email have a single-use token, or have them enter their email in order to view the file, and check that email against the subscriber list (and check to see if it has been used)

Comment: @David - Yes, but then *they* are the ones sending the bulk mail, not the OP

Answer (score 2):

Once someone has a recording of your voice, there isn't anything you can do to stop them from sending it to whoever they want.

Comment: so any workaround? If i have stored the voice email on my website then?

Comment: There is NOTHING from a technology perspective you can do to prevent someone from copying and resharing your content, if they so desire.

Comment: If they can listen to it, it's already on their computer. At that point you've lost all control over what they do with it.